# PostgreSQL, SELECT keeps adding Rows to Dataoutput

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I have a Track-geometry table with a bunch of rows. 
My primary Key is the ID of the single track. Its Datatype is bigint.
I got 4177 Rows in the table.

Now when i do: `Select * from mytable;` it shows me the dataoutput with 4177 rows with the informations.

When I execute `Select * from mytable;` again, the dataoutput adds 1000 Rows. Now I have 5177 Rows.

When I execute the statement again -> dataoutput with 7177 Rows.

When I execute: `Select Count (*) from mytable;` then it shows me 4177 Rows.

I dont get how the dataoutput is showing me more and more row (probably doubling some rows). The ID's are unique.
Other tables just show me the same rows in the dataoutput no matter how often I `Select * from othertable;`
I dont know if the columns and the table is important for that but since the table got private Informations i can't uploade the table.

Comment: Is there any chance someone/something is inserting records as you issue your various selects?  This is the only explanation of which I can think.

Comment: No i dont think so. Even when I issue my various selects the 'real number' throug 'Count' still remains 4711. The table is not beeing edited.

Comment: Can you show the exact data output for each execution?

Comment: Is there maybe an option in pgAdmin to _append_ new data to the current result?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't show the data output, since the information are private. But with the first Output it shows me all rows with all Information. When I execute the same statement (Select *) it is adding new rows, but not duplicatin all rows, just a few random. When I restart pgadmin it starts from the beginning.

Comment: can you share what tool do you use to execute your query and present your result? isn't just the tool fetching rows again and again adding them the the output? it makes no sense otherwise

Comment: Did you create this table? Could this be a view or function

Comment: I did create the table myself.I use PGAdmin 4. I have a few tables im working with currently and just this table is having this issues. The others are working fine...